# Change button Url Action after click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, button, href

Okay so I have this button:

```
<button name="nameButton" id="idButton" title="your title" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action( "AddToCollection","UserCollection", new {  gameId = Model.Id })'; return false;"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>Add To Collection</button>
```

How can I change the

```
@Url.Action( "AddToCollection","UserCollection", new {  gameId = Model.Id}
```

to lets say

```
@Url.Action( "RemoveFromCollection","UserCollection", new {  gameId = Model.Id}
```

I searched and couldn't figure out how to do it with jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Sometimes it's easiest to output both buttons and toggle their visibility conditionally. It saves changing the events they perform, their appearance, and the text they display.

Comment: Can you tell how to do that ?